# Web authentication API window in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, webauthn

I have a Chrome extension to which I want to implement user authentication by WebAuthn and for it im using 'webauthn' library, but after I call a command to create a passkey is cropping by extension border, are there any solutions to this except extension window width increasing?

[image]

I had already tried to increase the extension window width and it helped, but I want a more adaptive solution. I want to display WebAuthn window above the extension or automatically increase the extension width.